# How to access Table from one Azure SQL DW from another Azure SQL DW?

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I want to access table in another SQL DWH inside stored procedure in my current Azure SQL DWH.
I searched online found only methods for SQL Database only. Please tell if anyone has figured out any workaround.

PS: Is it possible to sync tables in two DWH, i.e, every time there is an update in table in one DWH it copies into same table in another DWH.

Answer (score 1):

The current release of Azure Synapse does not support cross-database queries.

Your best option to move data between instances of Azure Synapse is to use Polybase to export and import the data. You can schedule this activity using Azure Data Factory or Azure Functions.

Keep your eye on our up-coming announcements, we'll support your requirement for cross-database queries in the near future.